# Unable to Navigate using LinkText in Selenium C#

Tags: asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I got the following C# code from Selenium IDE:

```
  driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Sub Link 1")).Click();
```

But as it wasn't working, I modified the code below to wait. It is still not working.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement element =  wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.LinkText("Main Link 1")));
if (element != null)
{
    var innerElement = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.PartialLinkText( 
         "Sub Link 1")));
}
```

*What might be the possible issue?*

My HTML:

```
<html>
    <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation">Show navigation</a>
    <a href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide navigation</a>
    <div id="navlogo"><a title="HOME" href="url">
         <span style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left: 0;">
         </span></a></div>
    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li><a href="">MXLMain1</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="">ML1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">ML2</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">MXLMain2</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">MK2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Main Link 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Sub Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Sub Link 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
..........................
</html>
```

Comment: I remember I had some issue with linktext, it never find what i need, so every time when i want to search something with text, I'm using xpath for that, //a[text()='Sub Link 1']

Comment: Have you tried By.PartialLinkText. Sometimes the spaces around the text doesnt let the exact element find.

Comment: "Not working" means *what*? What errors?

Comment: Is this a dropdown where on Clicking "Main Link 1" user can see "Sub Link 1" & "Sub Link 2" ...if yes...then try clicking on "Main Link 1" and then try the same with "Sub Link 1" too..

Answer (score 0):

How about using xpath?

`driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[.='Sub Link 1")).Click();`

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like the link that you are trying to use is from a navigation bar. You will need to use Seleniums Actions class to activate the menu dropdown.
2. Then use Actions class to move to element and click on it.

   `public void MouseHover(By locator)
    {
       element = driver.FindElement(locator);
       Actions action = new Actions(driver);
       action.MoveToElement(element).Perform();
    }`

To click same steps.

```
action.MoveToElement(element).Perform();
action.Click().Perform();
```

1. Move to initial element
2. Move to the second element and use click method